# better way to automate c# gui applications controls using python

Tags: c#, user-interface, python-2.7, automation, pywinauto

is there better way to automate c# gui applications including datagridview and its internally added controls using python I tried with PywinAuto is there any other tool/ module available in python? Plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at PyWinAuto, then I assume you are asking about free/open-source, as opposed to commercial support. There are a host of commercial tools available. [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) and [white](http://teststack.github.com/White/) are good ones to check out.